# Using Powershell command how to get absolute URL of subsite of group resides in that subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, groups, sub-site

I am using powershell command remotely to communicate with SharePoint Server(2010/13 both). I am using following powershell command to fetch "SiteGroups" from site collections

```
Get-SPSite http://server/sites/yoursite |
  Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb |
  Select -ExpandProperty SiteGroups |
  Select {$_.ParentWeb.Url}, Name
```

But groups which are in a subsite inside a site collection also shown ParentWeb.Url as site collection URL. I want subsite's absoulte URL for those groups as those are belonging to subsite.

Can anybody suggest how to use get-spsite command to achieve this ?
Does ParentWeb has any property which can give me absoulte URL of subsite ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
function GetGroups($web)
{
    foreach ($g in $web.Groups) {
        Write-Host $web.Url, $g.Name
    }   
    foreach ($w in $web.Webs) {
        GetGroups($w)
    }   
}
```

It is a recursive function that visits all your webs and writes the groups related to the webs.
Execute the function, and then execute the following code, to call the function:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/yoursite
GetGroups($web)
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs .. but I forgot to mention , I want commands only as I will be firing it through .NET/C# application so don't have luxury to use script inside a C# application.

Comment: Ok, no problem. You'll definitely need some sort of recursive call since you need to check groups of every subweb in the structure.